# select multiple rows using MySQL in Perl

Tags: perl, dbi

am selecting 3 rows from MySQL

but am only getting first one that's - name. i only get name only

```
$get = $dbh->prepare("select name, age, country from tble where me = ?");
$get->execute('john');
while(my @row = $get->fetchrow_array){
     $results = $row[0],$row[1],$row[3];
  }
```

am just getting name only no other rows

Comment: What is the expected content of `$results`? Note that you are assigning a list to a scalar: `$results = $row[0],$row[1],$row[3]` which will truncate to the first item of the list, namely `$row[0]`

Comment: expected content is: name, age, country

Comment: Then you could try to put the variables in double quotes, to interpolate them into a scalar string:  `$results = "$row[0], $row[1], $row[3]";`

Comment: You could also use `$results = {name => $row[0], age => $row[1], country => $row[3]};` to make it a hash reference.

Comment: `my ($name, $age, $country) = @row;`  Also, there is no `$row[3]` element.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is a red herring here. You're using DBI correctly, but it goes wrong once you've extracted the data from the database.

Your problem is with this line:

```
$results = $row[0],$row[1],$row[3];
```

This is very similar to running this code:

```
$x = 100, 200, 300;
```

If you then print `$x` you'll see it contains "100". You have three items on the right-hand side of your assignment operator and only one variable on the left-hand side, so only one of the values (the first one) ends up assigned to the variable.

I'll add here that if you had `use warnings` turned on in your code (and all good Perl programmers always have `use strict` and `use warnings` turned on) then you would have got a warning about "useless use of a constant in void context" which would have indicated that there was something wrong.

There are a couple of approaches you can take to fix this. And which one you choose, depends on what you are trying to do. The obvious solution is to change `$results` into an array:

```
@results = ($row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
```

Notice I've also put parentheses around your list of values. These are required to tell Perl that this is a list assignment. Of course, this is just a complicated way of writing:

```
@results = @row;
```

The other option is to take your three values and turn them into a single string. This isn't a good choice if you're going to use those values individually elsewhere in your code, but if you just want something to print out, you could write something like:

```
$results = "$row[0],$row[1],$row[2]";
```

Again, there's a simpler way to write this:

```
$results = join ',', @row;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Name`, `age` and `country` aren’t rows — they are *columns*.

You can use [selectcol_arrayref](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectcol_arrayref) to get one column only:

```
$name_ref = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref(
    q{
        SELECT name
        FROM tble
        WHERE me = ?
    },
    {},
    'john'
);
```

But if you want to get three columns you should use [selectall_arrayref](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectall_arrayref)

```
my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
    q{
        SELECT name, age, country
        FROM FROM tble
        WHERE me = ?
    },
    { Slice => {} },
    'john'
);

foreach my $row ( @$rows ) {
    print "$row->{'name'} aged $row->{'age'} from $row->{'country'}\n";
}
```